# Is there anyway to get subscriptions by Azure API?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

Here is my token Authentication

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]));

var credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"]);

_token = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiEndpoint"], credential);
```

And yes I got the token now from https://management.core.windows.net/

After that I am creating a new instance of `SubscriptionClient` under `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager` namespace there is 2 different namespace for this but that is the one I am using.

Here is my instance

```
_credentials = new TokenCredentials(_managementToken.AccessToken);

_subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(_credentials);
```

And the finally here is the call

```
await _subscriptionClient.Subscriptions.ListAsync();
```

And returns nothing from that.

But from this call

```
await _subscriptionClient.Tenants.ListAsync();
```

this returns my tenant id.

BTW I am using **WEB APP** not a NATIVE APP.

Is there any solution for that. How can I get subscriptions from Management API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please firstly ensure your subscription has associated with your azure ad tenant :

1. In classic portal , click Settings menu in the left panel .
2. You could view the subscription information and the directory it associated with :
   [image]

Please ensure the azure ad tenant you are using has any subscription .

Comment: Thank you, something wrong with my account.  My other team mates accounts work fine.